# What was the plan that Daenerys abandoned?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In S8E3 of *Game of Thrones*, Jon unsuccessfully tries to stop Daenerys from leaving the mountain they are perched on as they watch the Dothraki get chewed up by the undead hordes. In the "Inside the Episode" after, one of the writers states that "the plan" begins to unravel when Daenerys takes off on Drogon.

Was this plan ever elaborated or alluded to? What were Daenerys and Jon waiting for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The plan as stated by Weiss in the same Inside the episode is

> *Weiss:* They have a plan and it's important to wait for the Night King to reveal himself & then have two dragons against one dragon and
>   a really good chance of defeating him.

[From Inside the episode with D&D](https://youtu.be/ZJ1yC3yESLQ?t=121)